# How to solve the concurrency conflict in ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency, ado.net

Such a scenario: a certain amount of data to be inserted in a table,when reaches a threshold no longer insert, I simulated this scenario, in the case of multi-threaded (eg asp.net) appeared concurrent problems.

My question is how to solve of the concurrent problem, do not use the `lock` case

```
void Main()
{

   Enumerable.Range(0,20).ToList().ForEach(i=>{
       MockMulit();
   });

}
//Start a certain number of threads for concurrent simulation
void MockMulit()
{
  int threadCount=100;

  ClearData();//delete all data for test


  var tasks=new List<Task>(threadCount);
  Enumerable.Range(1,threadCount).ToList().ForEach(i=>{
     var j=i;
     tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>T3(string.Format("Thread{0}-{1}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,j))));
  });
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

  CountData().Dump();//show that the result
}
```

method one - concurrency very serious

```
void T1(string name)
{
        using(var conn=GetOpendConn())
        {
            var count=conn.Query<int>(@"select count(*)  from dbo.Down").Single();
            if(count<20)
            {
                conn.Execute(@"insert into dbo.Down (UserName) values (@UserName)",new{UserName=name});
            }
        }

}
```

method two - put the sql together can reduce concurrent, but still exist

```
void T2(string name)
{
   using(var conn=GetOpendConn())
   {
       conn.Execute(@"
                      if((select count(*)  from dbo.Down)<20)
                        begin
                          --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100';
                          insert into dbo.Down (UserName) values (@UserName)
                        end",new{UserName=name});
   }
}
```

method three - with lock destroy the concurrent,but i don't think it is a best solution

```
private static readonly object countLock=new object();
void T3(string name)
{
    lock(countLock)
    {
        using(var conn=GetOpendConn())
        {
            var count=conn.Query<int>(@"select count(*)  from dbo.Down").Single();
            if(count<20)
            conn.Execute(@"insert into dbo.Down (UserName) values (@UserName)",new{UserName=name});
        }
    }
}
```

other help method

```
//delete all data
void ClearData()
{
   using(var conn=GetOpendConn())
   {
       conn.Execute(@"delete from dbo.Down");
   }
}
//get count
int CountData()
{
   using(var conn=GetOpendConn())
   {
      return conn.Query<int>(@"select count(*)  from dbo.Down").Single();
   }
}
//get the opened connection
DbConnection GetOpendConn()
{
    var conn=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestDemo;");
    if(conn.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
       conn.Open();
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: What type of database are you using that can't handle inserting data?

Comment: The scenario you are trying to protect against is very unclear. Can you perhaps rephrase what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually i was  design a Goods spike activity for our e-commerce website.For example, a Goods only 20 can buy , because asp.net is multi-thread,21 records appear in our database! :(

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you only want to insert into Down when there are less than 20 rows. If so: make that a single operation:

```
insert dbo.Down (UserName)
select @UserName
where (select count(1) from dbo.Down) < 20

select @@rowount -- 1 if we inserted, 0 otherwise
```

Alternatively, if you **need**you will need to use a transaction, ideally "Serializable", so that you get a key-range-lock - perhaps even adding `(UPDLOCK)` to the initial count, to ensure it takes an eager write lock (or blocks, rather than deadlocks). But: the single TSQL operation (as already illustrated is preferable. You could even make that more paranoid (although I'm not sure it needs it):

```
declare @count int

begin tran

insert dbo.Down (UserName)
select @UserName
where (select count(1) from dbo.Down (UPDLOCK)) < 20

set @count = @@rowount

commit tran

select @count -- 1 if we inserted, 0 otherwise
```

Comment: I was write a test(https://github.com/dushouke/ConcurrencyTest), make that a single operation can't solve the problem. But with the `UPDLOCK` can destroy the concurrent

Comment: @jefferydu no, `UPDLOCK` doesn't "destroy the concurrent" - it merely ***correctly*** indicates that we are planning to change this data in the same transaction (rather than just read it). Did you try the second version I posted?

Comment: yes,i tested the second version,no more records are inserted.The result screenshots http://i.stack.imgur.com/155ev.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing this in reverse and it will probably be much simpler. For example:

- Create a table with an auto-incrementing index. Call it "Up", or "RequestOrdering", or whatever.
- Get client requests in any order. For each request:

  - Insert a new row into Up.
  - Get the last inserted row ID.
  - If the last insert ID <= 20, do a real insert.
- Throw away your Up table when you're done with it.

If your database supports multi-column primary keys with one of them auto-incrementing (IIRC, MyISAM tables do), you could re-use the "Up" table across multiple product specials.

---

An even easier implementation would be insert 20 rows into "Down" and delete one per request. Check the number of affected rows (should be 1) to see if the user was successful. This plays nicely with multi-product specials. For example:

```
delete * from Down where down_special_id = Xxx limit 1
```

---

Probably easiest, and to also keep track of who "won", create one row per product and have each user update one (and only one) row. Again, check the number of affected rows to see if they were successful:

```
update Up
set
  user_name = @user_name
where
  user_name is null
  and product_id = @product_id
limit 1
```

Comment: Pardon the MySQL syntax. I think SQL Server and other like "TOP" vs "LIMIT".